# How to call the web service in Silverlight using web clinet

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight-4.0

I am calling web service from Silverlight using web client. I am stuck at getting the data from web service.

Let me know: is this process the correct way to get the result?

Below is the code I have used, but it is not fully correct.

```
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://[localhost]/CustomerPortalService12/AddAccount/" + "Expense");

var w = new WebClient();

var json_data = string.Empty; 

// attempt to download JSON data as a string

try
{
    w.DownloadStringCompleted += w_DownloadStringCompleted;
    w.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
catch (Exception) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

although your solution is correct and i believe there will be w_DownloadStringCompleted method somewhere in your code.

If you can try then look for Reactive Extension (Rx) which is well built library for handling  scenario like yours

Comment: thanks for your reply.if i call from consol application it is working.But when i call from siverlight i am getting error :System.Security.SecurityException